# How to initialize Faraday with a url of type "http://example.com/something"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, faraday

If I do:

```
conn = Faraday.new(url: 'http://example.com/api') do |builder|
  builder.adapter :httpclint
end
```

it removes `/api` from the base url and `conn.host` returns `"example.com"`. When I later do:

```
conn.post { |req| req.url '/resource'...}
```

it calls `example.com/resource`, instead of `example.com/api/resource`. How can I change that so it doesn't cut the base url?

I know I could initialize it with only `example.com` and then just do something like:

```
conn.post { |req| req.url '/api/resource'...}
```

but I want to store the base url in a global configuration, so that only the names of the resources are used in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omit the forward slash at the beginning of the request and it'll be relative to the initial URL you supplied. Otherwise, it will start from the root of the host:

```
conn.post { |req| req.url 'resource'...}  # Treated as example.com/api/resource
conn.post { |req| req.url '/resource'...} # Treated as example.com/resource
```

This is by design (See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/346))

Comment: Awesome! All the time I've been wondering why faraday cuts base connection URL